# How to show list of objects that contains images and bind it to source MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I want to show list of images and post some info about them below every image.
I tried passing `ObservableCollection` of my model and binding it, but it doesn't work. Right now I am passing `ObservableCollection` of *BitmapImages* and it is displaying images, but then I can't get info. Any ideas? I am working in WPF with MVVM.

What I tried so far:

**View:**

```
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ImageModels}" 
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" MaxHeight="550">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageModels.Data}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ImageModels.Title}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public ObservableCollection<ImageModel> ImageModels { get; set; }
```

**ImageModel**

```
private string description;
private string title;
private string path;
private BitmapImage data;

public short Id { get; set; }
public short UserId { get; set; }
public DateTime Created { get; set; }
public string Description
{
    get { return description; }
    set
    {
        if (description != value)
        {
            description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't showed u whole `ImageModel` but u get the point.
Most important property is `Data` because I use that one to populate source, or at least I am trying.
And when `ViewModel` is loaded I get images from DB and populate Data property of each image with `BitmapImage`, so that's why I'm using it for source.

Comment: What's inside your `ImageModels` class?

Comment: Data and Title must be public properties of the ImageModel class. The Bindings must be `{Binding Data}` and `{Binding Title}`. Also note that `ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"` does not bind to the `ImageModels` property (because it uses a different property name).

Comment: @dhilmathy I edited

Comment: @Clemens I property is called Images, I just pasted wrong one, that's not the problem. I can show u method where I populate ImageModel?

Comment: "Most important property is Data" - where is it?

Comment: @Clemens as I said, I didn't showed u whole `ImageModel`, property is presented like `Description`, I will edit question to show u method where I populate `Data`

Comment: Anyway, as already said, your Binding Paths are wrong. It should be `{Binding Data}`, not `{Binding ImageModels.Data}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `ImageModel` class will be like,

```
public class ImageModel 
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Your *ViewModel* property will be

```
public ObservableCollection<ImageModel> Images = new ObservableCollection<ImageModel>();
```

Your **XAML** should have *Binding* like

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding Path}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I don't really understand? I need list of objects and here I can show one object, am I wrong?

Comment: Okay I understand what u are trying to say. I will try it now

Comment: @Serlok As your `ItemsSource` is binded to collection of `ImageModel`, each `ListViewItem` will be of type `ImageModel`. So, you can just specify the property names alone in binding.

Comment: indeed, such a stupid mistake, but it was a long day of programming and with this I finished project, ty sir.